# Automatically registering class members to the containing object in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

**This is a question about C++ design:** how to avoid introducing a bug as a class changes.  The question title indicates my point of view of what I want, but might be the wrong strategy.

I have a class called `MyCell` that I collect in another class called `MyRow`.  Behind all of this is a database, and the row will, prior to destruction, want to persist itself to the database if any of its cells have changed.

```
class MyRowUser : public MyRow {
   public:
    MyRowUser() : MyRow() {}

    MyCell<int> registered_user_id;
    MyCell<int> birth_year;
    MyCell<UserGender> gender;
};

class MyTableUser : public MyTable {
    // Contains various things, including a collection
    // of MyRowUser objects.  Not relevant here, just
    // for context.
}
```

Now this isn't hard: I just have a function called `IsDirty()` in `MyRowUser` (or `MyRow` if I'm clever enough) that loops over the `MyCell` values and asks each one if it has changed.  If any has, then the row persists.

A class of error I'd like to avoid, however, is that I add a new `MyCell` member to a row and forget to add it to the `IsDirty()` function that loops over the cells.  And here I have not found a clever solution.  Every registration scheme I think of so that the row knows about the cells requires actually doing the registrations explicitly.  Notably, the MyCell constructors can't know about the Row (about `this`) in any automatic way I've thought of.

Any design suggestions on how to achieve this more robustly than my current manual iteration?

Comment: Seems like a classic observer to me. The row should be registering the cells as they are added.

Comment: @sweenish Agreed, the question is how to avoid manual registration of the observers, if it's even possible.  Imagine I add a new `MyCell` and forget to register it.  That creates a subtle hard to find bug.

Comment: Consider using [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) to iterate over fields. You could also use macros to define the row classes (then `IsDirty` can be generated automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like boiler plate, I got something for you:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// This you have to do once:

namespace detail {
template<class... Args>
constexpr void dump(Args...) {}


template<class T, auto en>
struct EnumTypePair {
    using type = T;
    static constexpr auto value = en;

    constexpr EnumTypePair() = default;

    constexpr EnumTypePair(const T&) noexcept {}

    template<class Tuple>
    static constexpr bool fits() {
        if constexpr(std::tuple_size_v<Tuple> > value) {
            if constexpr(std::is_same_v<typename std::tuple_element_t<static_cast<std::size_t>(value), Tuple>::type, type>) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

template<class T, auto en>
static constexpr EnumTypePair<T, en> t{};

template<class Cells, typename Cells::names... Ns, class... Ts>
constexpr bool check_cells(EnumTypePair<Ts, Ns> ...pairs) {
    using types = typename Cells::types;
    using names = typename Cells::names;
    static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<types> == static_cast<std::size_t>(names::MAX));
    return (pairs.template fits<types>() && ...);
}

}

template<class Row>
struct cells;

template<class T>
struct MyCell {
    T content;

    auto clean() {};
    using type = T;
};

template<class Cells, typename Cells::names name>
using cell_type = typename std::tuple_element_t<static_cast<std::size_t>(name), typename Cells::types>;

template<class Cells, typename Cells::names name>
using content_type = typename cell_type<Cells, name>::type;


template<class ...Ts>
using cell_tuple = std::tuple<MyCell<Ts>...>;

template<class Child>
struct Row {
    using names = typename cells<Child>::names;

    template<names name> 
    auto get_cell() -> cell_type<cells<Child>, name>& {
        return std::get<static_cast<std::size_t>(name)>(m_cells);
    }

    template<names name> 
    auto get() -> content_type<cells<Child>, name>& {
        return std::get<static_cast<std::size_t>(name)>(m_cells).content;
    }

    
    template<std::size_t ... Ns>
    void clean_impl(std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Ns...>) {
        detail::dump( get_cell<names(Ns)>()... );
    }

    auto make_clean() {
        clean_impl(std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, names::MAX>{});
    }

    typename cells<Child>::types m_cells;
};

// This you have to do for each row:

struct MyRow;

template<>
struct cells<MyRow> {
    enum names {
        id,
        birth_year,
        gender,
        MAX
    };
    
    using types = cell_tuple<int, int, char>;

    // To check against reordering
    static_assert(detail::check_cells<cells<MyRow>>(detail::t<int, id>, detail::t<int, birth_year>, detail::t<char, gender>));
};

struct MyRow: Row<MyRow> {
};


int main() {
    MyRow r;

    // This is sadly very verbose, maybe you have to write getters for every field.
    r.get<cells<MyRow>::id>() = 1;
}
```

It should be very hard to make an error but you also have to type a lot....

EDIT: By the power of fold expressions, I got rid of a lot of annoying stuff. And now it is impossible to forget the cleaning up. It needs a bit of boilerplate to protect you from reordering the elements and then having a bad day.

EDIT 2: I just saw, that you want to use C++14. This will make the order checking more annoying. The automatic clean up is no problem, I added a workaround for the pack expansion. And I fixed a problem with the integer_sequence.

Comment: This is really awesomely clever and does solve the problem stated.  I'm not entirely sure that the reduced readability (for other devs, for me in six months) makes it worthwhile, but just realising that this is possible is quite eye-opening.  So thanks for that!

Comment: We use C++14 because nothing has quite pushed us to upgrade to C++17 or C++20.  Some day that will have to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that you will never use `Cell`s outside of a common `MyRow` class and that `Cell` cannot contain `MyRow`s again, you could do the following:

```cpp
class MyRow {
  public:
    static MyRow* g_current_row;
    MyRow() : dirty(false) { g_current_row = this; }
    void makeDirty() { dirty = true; }
    void clearDirty() { dirty = false; }
    bool isDirty() const { return dirty; }

  private:
    bool dirty;
};
```

and use it in the `Cell` constructor:

```
Cell::Cell() : owner(MyRow::g_current_row) {}

void Cell::update(T value) { owner->makeDirty(); }
```

The `MyRowUser` constructor will call `MyRow::MyRow`, which sets `g_current_row` for the `Cell` constructors after it.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works.  I have a collection of `MyRow`s, each with its `current_row` member.  Then there's a registration function takes a row, is called by the `MyRow` constructor, and that creates and registers the `MyCell`s for that row?  And then there's some (typesafe??) accessor to the cells?

Comment: The `g_current_row` pointer is static (could use a `thread_local` variable too) and only used to tell the Cells which row is currently being constructed. What you do with the `g_current_row` pointer inside the `Cell` is up to you. I showed how a `Cell` can mark the `Row` it is in dirty if it is ever changed, that saves you from checking each `Cell` independently. You could just as well call `g_current_row->registerCell(this)` if you prefer.

Comment: This will not work. You set `g_current_row=this;` at the beginning of the destructor body, hence after the members got initialized. Therefore, the `g_current_row` used to initialize owner will be out of date (and uninitialized for the first row).

Comment: Note that I put this in the constructor of the **base class** `MyRow`. Thus, during construction of the **derived class** `MyRowUser` (where the `Cell`s are),  this constructor runs before the members are constructed. See [class.base.init, 13](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#13)

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sry.